# What is the SQL query that will give me the latest messageContent post for each senderId?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the below [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) table called message. I want a SQL query that will give me the latest `messageContent` post for each `senderId`?

| messageId | senderId | receiverId | public | messageTime | messageContent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | awe123 | awe123 | Y | 2020-12-14 20:40:06 | Shock and Awe, Baby! |
| 15 | ewm20 | ewm20 | Y | 2020-12-15 16:29:29 | Merry Christmas, everyone, to all a good night. |
| 16 | ewm20 | ewm20 | Y | 2020-12-16 21:27:09 | Rock On, Brother! |
| 17 | ewm20 | ewm20 | Y | 2020-12-16 23:27:19 | Steelers will make a comeback! |
| 18 | falcon9 | falcon9 | Y | 2020-12-17 02:06:50 | What! The Starship blew up??? When! |
| 19 | ewm20 | ewm20 | Y | 2020-12-17 02:22:35 | the Starship blew up on December 9th while landing. |
| 20 | ewm20 | ewm20 | Y | 2020-12-17 02:23:05 | It's velocity was too high. |
| 21 | ewm20 | ewm20 | Y | 2020-12-17 03:41:25 | However Musk is still optimistic about reaching Mars. |

The result would be something like:

| senderId | messageTime | messageContent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| awe123 | 2020-12-14 20:40 | Shock and Awe, Baby! |
| ewm20 | 2020-12-17 03:41 | However Musk is still optimistic about reaching Mars. |
| falcon9 | 2020-12-17 02:06 | What! The Starship |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of MySql does not support window functions, then:

```
select m.* from message m where messageTime = (
    select messageTime from message m2 where m2.senderId = m.senderId
    order by messageTime desc
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: Awesome Booboo, that finishes my functionality needed in my final web project. I will ensure you receive credit for it. I had to tweak the column names a little bit: mysqli did not like the "m." references on the column names. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windows function `row_number` as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by senderId order by messageTime  desc) as rn
   from your_table t) t
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Popeye. I got a derived table alias error code: 1248.

Comment: Done. Just need to give alias to the subquery.